# How to insert a \special at every linebreak

Tags: line-breaking

How can I make TeX/LaTeX insert the token `\special{lb}` into the generated DVI command stream whenever a linebreak occurs?

The `listings` package with its prebreak/postbreak option seems already close to the effect I want, however I need this `\special` to show up always, not only in case of a particular listing and I need this as a separate modification not as part of a package which might have side-effects.

The DVI commands are read as part of a postprocessing so I really need to see when TeX does a linebreak.

Comment: LuaTeX might help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: LuaTeX is not an option for non-technical reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply impossible. One should hook in the paragraph making algorithm, and this is not available to the user.

The only way is to use LuaTeX, that opens all the algorithms and procedures to user intervention.